# Is there any way to send data from aws lambda to firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

aws gateway http for auth0 authentication

which works fine and iam getting body data in aws lambda

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(event.body),
    };
    return response;
};
```

how to pass the body to aws firehose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [putRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Firehose.html#putRecord-property) or [putRecordBatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Firehose.html#putRecordBatch-property) AWS SDK methods for JavaScript.

You will also need to add firehose permissions to your lamnda's execution role.